# Problem using Select By Attribute tool in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

[image: Model and SQL error]

I tried to use the unique iterator value as input to select layer by attribute as expression then I got a syntax error.

Here is the attribute table:

[image: Attribute table]

Comment: Can you include your error as text rather than as a picture so that it can be available to future searches, please?

Comment: Try removing the quotes around %Value%

Comment: I tried but not working.

Comment: So what is this new error? You need to describe your problem better! Just saying it is not working helps no one, most of all you.

Comment: OK,good the error is  in the expression of select layer by attribute. Exactly the error is "an invalid sql expression was used.[select * from pri_Irr_hayelom_coordinates where code = %Value% ]". my intention is to make polygon from points.I used the iterate field values to select the unique values of code field from the attribute layer pri_Irr_hayelom_coordinates  then based on the unique values I need to select x and y which have the same code as shown in the attribute table, for example code 1. Then I will make line from the selected points then I will feed to polygon the output line, so on.

Answer (score 1):

You do not state what the data source format of pri_lrr_hayelom_cordinates is or give an example of what Value would be. So at this point we can only guess!

It could be one of two problems:

- Is your field `code` a text field? Your query is enclosing %Value% in SINGLE quotes indicating that value will be a string value.
- Depending upon the source of your data and if %value% is actually a string value you may need to enclose it in DOUBLE quotes.

Comment: The value and code are both have a data type of long.